# How to replicate touchpad zoom without thouchpad in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I found out that you can actually zoom in on Power BI report in Power BI Desktop by pinching in or stretching out two fingers on laptop touchpad.

This quite useful feature that I would like to replicate on desktop PC without touchpad. Any idea if this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pinch to zoom with a standard, cheap mouse on a PC. This is standard with a Magic Mouse on a Mac, but not on Windows machines. On a PC, there's the "magnifier" thing in Windows 10, but I don't think anyone on Earth really likes it. Maybe an advanced mouse would help you. Different browsers have a zoom you can use. For example, in Chrome, hold the `CTRL` button & use your wheel up & down. Not exactly like "pinch to zoom" but that's about as close as you can get. Essentially, the answer to your question is no.